# using jq to filter nested data in json

Tags: filter, jq

here is the original, it contains lots of information that i do not need for the purpose i am using it for.

```
[
  {
    "matchId": "2234705530498",
    "timestamp": 1661657182,
    "timeAgo": {
      "number": 17,
      "unit": "hours"
    },
    "clubs": {
      "79718": {
        "clubDivision": "4",
        "cNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
        "garaw": "3",
        "gfraw": "6",
        "losses": "0",
        "memberString": "6 / 6",
        "opponentClubId": "145078",
        "opponentScore": "3",
        "opponentTeamArtAbbr": "EASHL",
        "passa": "79",
        "passc": "58",
        "ppg": "0",
        "ppo": "0",
        "result": "1",
        "score": "6",
        "scoreString": "6 - 3",
        "shots": "15",
        "teamArtAbbr": "DROP",
        "teamSide": "1",
        "toa": "252",
        "winnerByDnf": "0",
        "winnerByGoalieDnf": "0",
        "details": {
          "name": "NZHL Memphis Make A Wish",
          "clubId": 79718,
          "regionId": 1,
          "teamId": 5108,
          "customKit": {
            "isCustomTeam": "1",
            "crestAssetId": "62",
            "useBaseAsset": "1"
          }
        },
        "goals": "6",
        "goalsAgainst": "3"
      },
      "145078": {
        "clubDivision": "6",
        "cNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
        "garaw": "6",
        "gfraw": "3",
        "losses": "1",
        "memberString": "6 / 6",
        "opponentClubId": "79718",
        "opponentScore": "6",
        "opponentTeamArtAbbr": "DROP",
        "passa": "101",
        "passc": "79",
        "ppg": "2",
        "ppo": "5",
        "result": "2",
        "score": "3",
        "scoreString": "3 - 6",
        "shots": "18",
        "teamArtAbbr": "EASHL",
        "teamSide": "0",
        "toa": "317",
        "winnerByDnf": "0",
        "winnerByGoalieDnf": "0",
        "details": {
          "name": "NZHL LOCAL CRAFT BEER",
          "clubId": 145078,
          "regionId": 6,
          "teamId": 5102,
          "customKit": {
            "isCustomTeam": "1",
            "crestAssetId": "234",
            "useBaseAsset": "1"
          }
        },
        "goals": "3",
        "goalsAgainst": "6"
      }
    },
    "players": {
      "145078": {
        "169580763": {
          "class": "2",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "157",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "rightWing",
          "posSorted": "3",
          "ratingDefense": "55.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "4",
          "skgoals": "2",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "3",
          "skpassattempts": "11",
          "skpasses": "7",
          "skpasspct": "63.64",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "1",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "106",
          "skppg": "1",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "12",
          "skshotonnetpct": "66.67",
          "skshotpct": "25.00",
          "skshots": "8",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Ababo"
        },
        "174908181": {
          "class": "14",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "190",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "1",
          "ratingDefense": "65.00",
          "ratingOffense": "75.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "80.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "4",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "5",
          "skinterceptions": "6",
          "skpassattempts": "32",
          "skpasses": "28",
          "skpasspct": "87.50",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "259",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "5",
          "skshotonnetpct": "20.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "3",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "mikezaw4458"
        },
        "181235555": {
          "class": "1",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "231",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "center",
          "posSorted": "5",
          "ratingDefense": "60.00",
          "ratingOffense": "90.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "75.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "3",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "1",
          "skfol": "14",
          "skfopct": "56.25",
          "skfow": "18",
          "skgiveaways": "8",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "20",
          "skpasses": "14",
          "skpasspct": "70.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "2",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "202",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "LedvinKa"
        },
        "1627813040": {
          "class": "2",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "230",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "leftWing",
          "posSorted": "4",
          "ratingDefense": "60.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "12",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "2",
          "skpassattempts": "23",
          "skpasses": "18",
          "skpasspct": "78.26",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "2",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "207",
          "skppg": "1",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "7",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "14.29",
          "skshots": "7",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Justn I87I"
        },
        "1785195119": {
          "class": "15",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "117",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "2",
          "ratingDefense": "35.00",
          "ratingOffense": "60.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "60.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "2",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "6",
          "skpassattempts": "13",
          "skpasses": "11",
          "skpasspct": "84.62",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "93",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "bostonsniper4t4"
        },
        "1004176504213": {
          "class": "21",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "1",
          "glga": "6",
          "glgaa": "6.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.60",
          "glsaves": "9",
          "glshots": "15",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "opponentScore": "6",
          "opponentTeamId": "501",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "156",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "goalie",
          "posSorted": "0",
          "ratingDefense": "70.00",
          "ratingOffense": "30.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "45.00",
          "score": "3",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "0",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "0",
          "skpassattempts": "0",
          "skpasses": "0",
          "skpasspct": "0.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "0",
          "skpossession": "0",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "0",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "teamId": "500",
          "teamSide": "0",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "HABSFAN972651"
        }
      },
      "79718": {
        "273323046": {
          "class": "2",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "140",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "rightWing",
          "posSorted": "3",
          "ratingDefense": "95.00",
          "ratingOffense": "100.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "30.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "3",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "2",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "7",
          "skpassattempts": "16",
          "skpasses": "12",
          "skpasspct": "75.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "2",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "241",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "3",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "33.33",
          "skshots": "3",
          "sktakeaways": "6",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "59",
          "toiseconds": "3567",
          "playername": "Gronk x L87L"
        },
        "288926878": {
          "class": "2",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "107",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "leftWing",
          "posSorted": "4",
          "ratingDefense": "65.00",
          "ratingOffense": "100.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "55.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "2",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "5",
          "skgoals": "3",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "1",
          "skpassattempts": "11",
          "skpasses": "8",
          "skpasspct": "72.73",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "183",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "8",
          "skshotonnetpct": "75.00",
          "skshotpct": "50.00",
          "skshots": "6",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "xxJONx"
        },
        "515447555": {
          "class": "15",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "125",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "2",
          "ratingDefense": "70.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "30.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "11",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "6",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "9",
          "skpasses": "5",
          "skpasspct": "55.56",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "6",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "212",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "2",
          "skshotonnetpct": "50.00",
          "skshotpct": "100.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "57",
          "toiseconds": "3404",
          "playername": "vShotsy"
        },
        "800554172": {
          "class": "15",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "1",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "214",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "1",
          "ratingDefense": "90.00",
          "ratingOffense": "95.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "2",
          "skbs": "1",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "10",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "6",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "26",
          "skpasses": "20",
          "skpasspct": "76.92",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "2",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "221",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "2",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "100.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "58",
          "toiseconds": "3481",
          "playername": "Martinez1225"
        },
        "858674479": {
          "class": "21",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "1",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "3",
          "glgaa": "3.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.83",
          "glsaves": "15",
          "glshots": "18",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "91",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "goalie",
          "posSorted": "0",
          "ratingDefense": "75.00",
          "ratingOffense": "75.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "60.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "0",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "0",
          "skpassattempts": "0",
          "skpasses": "0",
          "skpasspct": "0.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "0",
          "skpossession": "0",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "0",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "MacShrimp"
        },
        "1183100664": {
          "class": "1",
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "isGuest": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "opponentScore": "3",
          "opponentTeamId": "500",
          "player_dnf": "0",
          "playerLevel": "135",
          "pNhlOnlineGameType": "5",
          "position": "center",
          "posSorted": "5",
          "ratingDefense": "100.00",
          "ratingOffense": "80.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "65.00",
          "score": "6",
          "skassists": "2",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "18",
          "skfopct": "43.75",
          "skfow": "14",
          "skgiveaways": "1",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "2",
          "skpassattempts": "16",
          "skpasses": "12",
          "skpasspct": "75.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "103",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "200.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "2",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "teamId": "501",
          "teamSide": "1",
          "toi": "60",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Rakkarak"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

this is what i would like the output to be, with some of the values being dynamic.

```
                    [
                      {
                        "matchId": "2234705530498",
                        "timestamp": 1661657182,
                        "clubs": {
    this will be dynamic "79718": {
                            "passa": "79",
                            "passc": "58",
                            "ppg": "0",
                            "ppo": "0",
                            "shots": "15",
                            "toa": "252",
                            "details": {
                            "name": "NZHL Memphis Make A Wish",
                            "clubId": 79718,
                            }
                          },
                        },
                        "players": {
    this will be dynamic "145078": {
                            "169580763": {
                            "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
                            "glbrksaves": "0",
                            "glbrkshots": "0",
                            "gldsaves": "0",
                            "glga": "0",
                            "glgaa": "0.00",
                            "glpensavepct": "0.00",
                            "glpensaves": "0",
                            "glpenshots": "0",
                            "glpkclearzone": "0",
                            "glpokechecks": "0",
                            "glsavepct": "0.00",
                            "glsaves": "0",
                            "glshots": "0",
                            "glsoperiods": "0",
                            "opponentClubId": "79718",
                            "position": "rightWing",
                            "posSorted": "3",
                            "ratingDefense": "55.00",
                            "ratingOffense": "85.00",
                            "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
                            "skassists": "0",
                            "skbs": "0",
                            "skdeflections": "0",
                            "skfol": "0",
                            "skfopct": "0.00",
                            "skfow": "0",
                            "skgiveaways": "4",
                            "skgoals": "2",
                            "skgwg": "0",
                            "skhits": "1",
                            "skinterceptions": "3",
                            "skpassattempts": "11",
                            "skpasses": "7",
                            "skpasspct": "63.64",
                            "skpenaltiesdrawn": "1",
                            "skpim": "0",
                            "skpkclearzone": "0",
                            "skplusmin": "-5",
                            "skpossession": "106",
                            "skppg": "1",
                            "sksaucerpasses": "0",
                            "skshg": "0",
                            "skshotattempts": "12",
                            "skshotonnetpct": "66.67",
                            "skshotpct": "25.00",
                            "skshots": "8",
                            "sktakeaways": "0",
                            "toiseconds": "3600",
                            "playername": "Ababo"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
```

I have been trying multiple configurations with map, select, flatten, with_entries, and many others with no luck. would appreciate any help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you describe in words how the output is supposed to be built up? Looks like you want to pick properties from one of the objects, but how do you determine what properties to copy over?

Comment: @JeffMercado this is the stats information for a video game I play. We have leagues and stats that we have to manually input every night. I'm trying to build a way to automate this. The properties are the stats that are needed for our record keeping, and everything else is not needed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please adhere to the guidelines at [mcve] as much as possible, esp. the “m” part.

Comment: @peak thanks for you input. That is the minimum of the code I could post and guarantee a solution. You see jq doesn't always give the most information of why something is an error, just that there is one. So if there was a problem with the Json it's self, I would not know without posting the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could approach it. First map out the properties you want copied over, then filter each of the properties you want to filter to add or remove from each.

It's not exactly clear to me how you choose what fields to copy but making some assumptions:

```
map(
    # 1. select the properties
    {
        matchId,
        timestamp,
        clubs,
        players
    }
    |
    # 2. filter the properties
    .clubs[] |= ( # update each club...
        # 1. select the properties
        with_entries(select(.key | startswith("p"))) + {shots, toa, details}
        |
        # 2. filter the properties
        .details |= {name, clubId}
    )
    |
    .players[][] |= ( # update each player in the map of players
        # 1. select the properties
        with_entries(select(.key | startswith("gl")))
        +
        {opponentClubId, position, posSorted}
        +
        with_entries(select(.key | startswith("rating")))
        +
        with_entries(select(.key | startswith("sk")))
        +
        {toiseconds, playername}
    )
)
```

Produces the result:

```json
[
  {
    "matchId": "2234705530498",
    "timestamp": 1661657182,
    "clubs": {
      "79718": {
        "passa": "79",
        "passc": "58",
        "ppg": "0",
        "ppo": "0",
        "shots": "15",
        "toa": "252",
        "details": {
          "name": "NZHL Memphis Make A Wish",
          "clubId": 79718
        }
      },
      "145078": {
        "passa": "101",
        "passc": "79",
        "ppg": "2",
        "ppo": "5",
        "shots": "18",
        "toa": "317",
        "details": {
          "name": "NZHL LOCAL CRAFT BEER",
          "clubId": 145078
        }
      }
    },
    "players": {
      "145078": {
        "169580763": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "rightWing",
          "posSorted": "3",
          "ratingDefense": "55.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "4",
          "skgoals": "2",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "3",
          "skpassattempts": "11",
          "skpasses": "7",
          "skpasspct": "63.64",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "1",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "106",
          "skppg": "1",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "12",
          "skshotonnetpct": "66.67",
          "skshotpct": "25.00",
          "skshots": "8",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Ababo"
        },
        "174908181": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "1",
          "ratingDefense": "65.00",
          "ratingOffense": "75.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "80.00",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "4",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "5",
          "skinterceptions": "6",
          "skpassattempts": "32",
          "skpasses": "28",
          "skpasspct": "87.50",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "259",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "5",
          "skshotonnetpct": "20.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "3",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "mikezaw4458"
        },
        "181235555": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "center",
          "posSorted": "5",
          "ratingDefense": "60.00",
          "ratingOffense": "90.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "75.00",
          "skassists": "3",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "1",
          "skfol": "14",
          "skfopct": "56.25",
          "skfow": "18",
          "skgiveaways": "8",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "20",
          "skpasses": "14",
          "skpasspct": "70.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "2",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "202",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "LedvinKa"
        },
        "1627813040": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "leftWing",
          "posSorted": "4",
          "ratingDefense": "60.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "12",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "2",
          "skpassattempts": "23",
          "skpasses": "18",
          "skpasspct": "78.26",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "2",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "207",
          "skppg": "1",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "7",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "14.29",
          "skshots": "7",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Justn I87I"
        },
        "1785195119": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "2",
          "ratingDefense": "35.00",
          "ratingOffense": "60.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "60.00",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "2",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "6",
          "skpassattempts": "13",
          "skpasses": "11",
          "skpasspct": "84.62",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "-5",
          "skpossession": "93",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "bostonsniper4t4"
        },
        "1004176504213": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "1",
          "glga": "6",
          "glgaa": "6.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.60",
          "glsaves": "9",
          "glshots": "15",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "79718",
          "position": "goalie",
          "posSorted": "0",
          "ratingDefense": "70.00",
          "ratingOffense": "30.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "45.00",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "0",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "0",
          "skpassattempts": "0",
          "skpasses": "0",
          "skpasspct": "0.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "0",
          "skpossession": "0",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "0",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "HABSFAN972651"
        }
      },
      "79718": {
        "273323046": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "rightWing",
          "posSorted": "3",
          "ratingDefense": "95.00",
          "ratingOffense": "100.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "30.00",
          "skassists": "3",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "2",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "7",
          "skpassattempts": "16",
          "skpasses": "12",
          "skpasspct": "75.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "2",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "241",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "3",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "33.33",
          "skshots": "3",
          "sktakeaways": "6",
          "toiseconds": "3567",
          "playername": "Gronk x L87L"
        },
        "288926878": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "leftWing",
          "posSorted": "4",
          "ratingDefense": "65.00",
          "ratingOffense": "100.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "55.00",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "2",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "5",
          "skgoals": "3",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "1",
          "skpassattempts": "11",
          "skpasses": "8",
          "skpasspct": "72.73",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "183",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "8",
          "skshotonnetpct": "75.00",
          "skshotpct": "50.00",
          "skshots": "6",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "xxJONx"
        },
        "515447555": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "2",
          "ratingDefense": "70.00",
          "ratingOffense": "85.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "30.00",
          "skassists": "1",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "11",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "6",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "9",
          "skpasses": "5",
          "skpasspct": "55.56",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "6",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "212",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "1",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "2",
          "skshotonnetpct": "50.00",
          "skshotpct": "100.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "toiseconds": "3404",
          "playername": "vShotsy"
        },
        "800554172": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "defenseMen",
          "posSorted": "1",
          "ratingDefense": "90.00",
          "ratingOffense": "95.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "70.00",
          "skassists": "2",
          "skbs": "1",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "10",
          "skgoals": "1",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "6",
          "skinterceptions": "4",
          "skpassattempts": "26",
          "skpasses": "20",
          "skpasspct": "76.92",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "2",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "221",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "2",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "100.00",
          "skshotpct": "100.00",
          "skshots": "1",
          "sktakeaways": "1",
          "toiseconds": "3481",
          "playername": "Martinez1225"
        },
        "858674479": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "1",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "3",
          "glgaa": "3.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.83",
          "glsaves": "15",
          "glshots": "18",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "goalie",
          "posSorted": "0",
          "ratingDefense": "75.00",
          "ratingOffense": "75.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "60.00",
          "skassists": "0",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "0",
          "skfopct": "0.00",
          "skfow": "0",
          "skgiveaways": "0",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "0",
          "skinterceptions": "0",
          "skpassattempts": "0",
          "skpasses": "0",
          "skpasspct": "0.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "0",
          "skplusmin": "0",
          "skpossession": "0",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "0",
          "skshotonnetpct": "0.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "0",
          "sktakeaways": "0",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "MacShrimp"
        },
        "1183100664": {
          "glbrksavepct": "0.00",
          "glbrksaves": "0",
          "glbrkshots": "0",
          "gldsaves": "0",
          "glga": "0",
          "glgaa": "0.00",
          "glpensavepct": "0.00",
          "glpensaves": "0",
          "glpenshots": "0",
          "glpkclearzone": "0",
          "glpokechecks": "0",
          "glsavepct": "0.00",
          "glsaves": "0",
          "glshots": "0",
          "glsoperiods": "0",
          "opponentClubId": "145078",
          "position": "center",
          "posSorted": "5",
          "ratingDefense": "100.00",
          "ratingOffense": "80.00",
          "ratingTeamplay": "65.00",
          "skassists": "2",
          "skbs": "0",
          "skdeflections": "0",
          "skfol": "18",
          "skfopct": "43.75",
          "skfow": "14",
          "skgiveaways": "1",
          "skgoals": "0",
          "skgwg": "0",
          "skhits": "1",
          "skinterceptions": "2",
          "skpassattempts": "16",
          "skpasses": "12",
          "skpasspct": "75.00",
          "skpenaltiesdrawn": "0",
          "skpim": "0",
          "skpkclearzone": "3",
          "skplusmin": "5",
          "skpossession": "103",
          "skppg": "0",
          "sksaucerpasses": "0",
          "skshg": "0",
          "skshotattempts": "1",
          "skshotonnetpct": "200.00",
          "skshotpct": "0.00",
          "skshots": "2",
          "sktakeaways": "2",
          "toiseconds": "3600",
          "playername": "Rakkarak"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You could of course combine a lot of the clauses in the filtering steps but I tried to set it up in an easily repeatable way and trying to preserve the key order

Comment: Thank you, that should work. I'll try in a bit. I just could not figure out how to select the properties inside objects clubs and players. But it looks like this should get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation that you can provide regex patterns for the paths to select.

Per segment matches

```
[
    ["matchId"],
    ["timestamp"],
    ["clubs", ".+", "p.+"],
    ["clubs", ".+", "(shots|toa)"],
    ["clubs", ".+", "details", "(name|clubId)"],
    ["players", ".+", ".+", "gl.+"],
    ["players", ".+", ".+", "(opponentClubId|position|posSorted)"],
    ["players", ".+", ".+", "rating.+"],
    ["players", ".+", ".+", "sk.+"],
    ["players", ".+", ".+", "(toiseconds|playername)"]
] as $patterns
|
def select_paths($patterns):
    def is_matching_pattern($path):
        ([$path, .] | transpose) as $pairs
        |
        all($pairs[]; . as [$path, $pattern] |
            $path | if $pattern then test("^(\($pattern))$") else false end
        )
        ;
    def filter_paths: . as [$path] |
        select(length == 1 or any($patterns[]; is_matching_pattern($path)))
        ;
    fromstream(tostream | filter_paths)
    ;
map(select_paths($patterns))
```

Dotted path matches

```
[
    "matchId",
    "timestamp",
    "clubs\\..+\\.p.+",
    "clubs\\..+\\.(shots|toa)",
    "clubs\\..+\\.details\\.(name|clubId)",
    "players\\..+\\..+\\.gl.+",
    "players\\..+\\..+\\.(opponentClubId|position|posSorted)",
    "players\\..+\\..+\\.rating.+",
    "players\\..+\\..+\\.sk.+",
    "players\\..+\\..+\\.(toiseconds|playername)"
] as $patterns
|
def select_paths($patterns):
    def is_matching_pattern($path): "^(\(.))$" as $pattern |
        $path | test($pattern)
        ;
    def filter_paths: . as [$path] |
        select(length == 1 or any($patterns[]; is_matching_pattern($path | join("."))))
        ;
    fromstream(tostream | filter_paths)
    ;
map(select_paths($patterns))
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I was wondering if you would be able to help me with another issue. I thought with filtering it would have fixed both, but it did not. Has to do with Json to CSV. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547586/converting-json-to-csv-using-command-linejq-json2csv-other/73555732#73555732)